# Handle database saves when the same as checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, sql, database, user-interface, angular5

I have a form as User Interface which has permanent and temporary address and a check-Box, If both addresses are same if we check a check box it should handle that and save in the database and these fields are in the same table. If not I need to manually enter. How can I handle the logic ? I use angular 5 in front end and back-end I use JAVA. Is that something I need to do with the database and UI?

I have got this example from stackOverflow but thats right back in angular js would like to know in angular 5
[handling database saves for checkboxes in angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34195086/angularjs-copy-the-value-of-one-input-box-to-another-input-box-only-if-checkbox)

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you have any code you have worked on so far?

Comment: If what you want is to auto fill one set of textfield from another set you are talking javascript? If so the question should not be tagged Java

Comment: I dont have a code yet, It should copy the same address of temporary and permanent on UI side on checking a check-box and save in the Database.

Comment: @StefanEmanuelsson yes it is a javascript

Comment: @StefanEmanuelsson if its a java-script code How should be the logic, This was my interview question. I couldn't find the proper answers on internet.

Comment: @rmlan Its similar to the form page example we come across every day. Let me know if still its not clear